# Showing different page layouts based on form data

Tags: views, 7, forms

I'm trying to build a multi step form. Before the second step I have to process the data inserted in step one and render different layout and form fields based on the results.

I use "drupal_get_form" callback in _menu hooks to display the form, but I think I have to use a different approach, because I can't find a way to specify a template and\or HTML code this way.

What can I do? Thanks!

MENU DECLARATION:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function clientform_menu() {
    $items['clientform/step1'] = array(
        'title' => "Estimate",
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=>array('clientform_step1'));

    return $items;
}

function clientform_step1($form, &$form_state){
    if(isset($form_state['values'])) {
        $currstep = $form_state['step'] + 1;
    }else {
        $currstep = 0;
    }

    $form_state['step'] = $currstep;
    $allsteps = getForm();
    $currform =  $allsteps[$currstep];

    return $currform;
}

function clientform_step1_submit($form, &$form_state){
    $form_state['storedvalues'][$form_state['step']] = $form_state['values'];
    if($form_state['step'] + 1 != getNumberOfSteps()) {
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    }else {

        //Reached end of multipage form

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want on the different pages of the form? Have you taken a look at webform and conditional fields? You might be able to do all of this via the UI.

Comment: @Andy each page of the wizard has a slightly different layout, namely button positions, divs... for now I manage to solve with #prefix and #suffix, hardcoding the layout in the form declaration, but I wonder if there is a better way, like plain html with some php inline (ex: <?php echo "Field Value" ?>) in template files.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a "theme callback" in a menu declaration, but that would only work if you had some way to distinguish which page/step the user is on.

The only other way I can think of would be to have some if/then statements in your form that check for what step the user is on, and alter the form how you need.

Comment: I'm a newbie of Drupal, can you provide me an example? I'll update my question with my menu declaration.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea: 
what if you split you form in 2 forms
The first form will be composed of the first 2 steps
Then you create a Rule which, on Form1 Submission, Elaborates the data and redirect the user to the second form.

If you don't need extremely complex thing, this should work just fine. I used this strategy in one case and it worked nicely. Not to mention that it is very flexible and can be modified also by inexpert users.

Comment: Mmmm, can I create a specific layout for the second form page based on previous processing by this way? I'm kind of newbie with Drupal :\

Comment: you can customize the layout with Display Suite and than you can do everything with CSS. I am not sure if you can have different layouts for the same content type, BUT if you choose a smart layout with Display then you have really no limits using CSS. You can enable CSS on different pages using many methods such as jQuery or conditionally including css using php...or use css injector module to inject different css depending on the page